# Why does the code shown below only work if certain parts arent included?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Why does the code shown below only work if certain parts arent included, i have two files but only one of them shows the real problem so i will focus on that one for now. Im going a bit insane because im searching for a solution for about 2 1/2 hours now.

```
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
  return (

    
    <div className='App'>
      <h1> Hi </h1>
      
      
      <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar/>
          <Routes>
          <Route path='./Navbar' exact/>
          </Routes>
      </Router>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

the h1 here i set the text too hi for the example only gets shown on my website when i delete my entire Router Navbar and any other container below

Comment: <> and </>, is that meant to be <div> and </div>? It looks like you have broken html.

Comment: <></> is fine, it is a Fragment. I can't reproduce your error. Do you see error messages when you open the Developer Tools console? And what version of React is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code actually was working right, after testing in Code Sandbox. There are Issues on the webpage with TypeErrors and uncaught hook exceptions. Those got fixed after merging the two package.json files i got by installing the react-router-dom in the wrong directory